# Problems inheriting inner java class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating an android live wallpaper using Kotlin. This requires a class that extends WallpaperService, which contains an inner class that extends WallpaperService.Engine.

So I've written this:

```
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine

public class MyWallpaperService : WallpaperService() {

    override fun onCreateEngine(): Engine = MyEngine()

    private inner class MyEngine : Engine() {

    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following 2 errors at compile time:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Error generating constructors of class MyEngine with kind IMPLEMENTATION 

Error:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Don't know how to generate outer expression for lazy class MyWallpaperService
```

I cant figure out why this is happening so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I have found is to use an intermediate Java class:

```java
public class Intermediate extends WallpaperService.Engine {
    public Intermediate(WatchfaceService outer) {
        outer.super();
    }
}
```

Then the inner class in your Kotlin WallpaperService should inherit Intermediate, passing the outer class as parameter.

```
public class MyWallpaperService : WallpaperService() {
    override fun onCreateEngine(): Engine = MyEngine()
​
    private inner class MyEngine : Intermediate(this) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [KT-6727](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6727)

You can try the following workaround:

```
private inner class MyEngine : super.Engine() {
}
```

Comment: Issue K-6727 was marked duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3335 which has been marked as fixed.  is this still a problem, or now resolved?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else searching through this issue I'd like to point out that this now works in Kotlin
( i'm using 1.4.10 I haven't verified what version this was fixed).

Key to remember is that the Engine has to be marked an **inner class** or Kotlin won't know how to reference the Engine being inherited.

```
class SampleService : WallpaperService() {

// region override
override fun onCreateEngine(): Engine {

    return IntermediateEngine()
}

// endregion

// region inner class

inner class IntermediateEngine() : Engine() {

    
}

// endregion
```

}